# How to clean up a vector/map properly?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, dictionary

If I have a `vector<string*> *vect` or a `map<pair<string*, int*>, string*> *map`,
how to clean up everything (including all object the vector/map contains)?
(Everything <sub>(vector, map, contents, string, ints)</sub> is allocated with `new`)

Is this enough:

```
delete vect;
delete map;
```

Comment: Why do you store pointers in containers? Especially int* is very likely wrong.

Comment: @Rudi: Oh, I'm new to C++. What is wrong with it?

Comment: int* simply wastes performance for no benefit, but even string* means manually managing creation and deletion, and the risks that implies. Just use strings and ints and your deletes will tidy up everything for you

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: On almost any modern architecture, `int*` will take as much space as `int` or even more. Not to mention the pain that comes with raw pointers. Avoid using pointers in `C++` unless they are absolutely needed.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux If you do not allocate the strings at any other part in your program (=you want to store the values in the container, not references) it is better to store the strings directly, and let the container do the nasty memory managing stuff. You only need to store pointers when the container contains references to other variables, which might be changed by other program parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you must iterate through the `vector`/ `map`, remove and delete its items one by one (which, as @SB pointed out, may require disposing of their members recursively).

(You could get away by simply deleting the items, ***if*** you are absolutely sure no one will access the vector elements anymore before the vector gets deleted - but it is still safer to remove each item before deleting it. This ensures program correctness at any point, eliminating the possibility for subtle bugs and easing maintenance in the long term.)

By the way this is one of the reasons why it is recommended to store smart pointers in collections, instead of raw pointers.

Comment: People like using smart-pointers so much that they often overlook boosts pointer-containers. They are made for this exact scenario.

Comment: +1 For answering the question and pointing out that smart pointers can solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

You really should consider using *smart pointers*.

```
vector<boost::shared_ptr<std::string> >* some_vector = new std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<std::string> >;

some_vector->push_back(boost::shared_ptr<std::string>("Hello World !"));

delete some_vector; // This will delete the contained std::string's as well
some_vector = NULL;
```

Basically, a *smart pointer* takes care of the life-cycle of the pointed data. They can even do much more (such a counting references, and so on) but I suggest you read [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) to learn more about the different types of *smart pointers*.

You can even specify a custom "freeing" function to use, instead of the default (`delete`).

Comment: Just to mention, since you said you're new to `C++`: if you ever try my code: the space between the two `>` is not part of my coding style: it is **needed** so the compiler doesn't interpret two `>` as the `>>` operator. If you're using `C++0x`, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

No, you must manually iterate over each container and call delete on the pointers it contains.  The vector didn't allocate that memory, so it's not going to clean it up for you.

If you use smart pointers then the pointer itself will handle deallocating it's memory.  Otherwise, you must balance your manual allocation with manual deallocation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider [Boost Pointer Container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html). It handles all the cleaning up and, in my experience, normal containers can seamlessly (meaning without breaking code) be replaced by these ones.

A pointer container expresses ownership of the contained objects by the container, which is what you have here (otherwise you wouldn't have to clean it up).

A container of smart-pointers is different, because the objects may live longer than the container. Also, there may be a small performance-penalty when using smart-pointers, but that really depends on the size of your containers and the type of operations you perform on them.